# Angular Container Component Architecture - Should Container Accept an @Input?

Tags: angular

I have an component that will listen to scroll events, and generate a Table of Contents based on the sections of a page. I've been using Container/Presentation component architecture up to this point - and none of the Containers accept any `@Input`s as they are `<router-outlet>` level components.

The container I have at present will most likely accept the page titles as an `@Input`. Now I could create a service and pass them in this way, but it does not seem logical - it's a container component, but it's projected into another component as it's `ng-content`, and the parent component will have the array it needs (hence simply binding to the @Input seems like the logical thing to do)

**Is it breaking the Smart/Container - Presentation component architecture by having a Container that accepts an `@Input`?**

**Note:** I don't think this is a strictly *opinion based* question, I think it's pretty specific as it's about the architecture convention

Comment: I feel the service would be the best solution, why do you think it is not logical?

Comment: It's a Container Component, but it's still a component, and it needs to accept an Input. I could make a service, but it would be doing exactly the same as the Input, just in a round about way. Nothing else would use that servcie, as all it would provide is an array of strings (the id's of the page sections)